# How do I report bugs about HUD?

Tags: bug-reporting, hud

I've found a couple of bugs in HUD, such as when you use it, the window loses focus afterwards. But I can't find a bug tracker for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to one of the developers, [file a bug against the indicator-appmenu project](http://pad.lv/fb/indicator-appmenu).

> Merges and bugs should be directed towards the indicator-appmenu project

- http://gould.cx/ted/blog/Searching_menus
- http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/01/testing-hud-heads-up-display.html
- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)